# Split a String when character is different to preceeding one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split a string taken from the user when the character at position K is different to K-1

I am having a some difficulties however.

Here is what I have so far:

```
UserInput = input("hi enter a string:")

Groups = []

for x in range(len(UserInput)):
    if (UserInput[x] != UserInput[x-1]):
        print(UserInput[x])
```

If you dont understand what I want here is an example:
Say the user entered: b444Mrr--<<<]0
I want to output on the screen: b, 444, M, rr, --, <<<, ], 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **[itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)**, observe:

```
import itertools

user_input = input("Please enter a string:")
groups = []

for _, group in itertools.groupby(user_input):
  groups.append(''.join(group))

print('Here is that string split when a character changes: %s' % ', '.join(groups))
```

**Example usage with given example:**

```
Please enter a string: b444Mrr--<<<]0
Here is that string split when a character changes: b, 444, M, rr, --, <<<, ], 0
```

***N.B.*** In Python use [**snake_case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) rather than [**TitleCase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Title_Case) (what you are doing in your attempt) or  [**camelCase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: Wow this is great 

Answer (score 1):

you can use the logic that unicode value is different for each char and can be used for the comparison for different chars like below code:-

```
inp=input("Enter String ")

prev=ord(inp[0])
str1=inp[0]
str=inp[1:]
for i in str:
    curr=ord(i)
    if prev==curr:
        str1=str1+i
    elif prev!=curr:
        print(str1)
        prev=curr
        str1=""
        str1=i        
print(str1)
```

**Example to demonstrate:-**

```
Enter String b444Mrr--<<<]0
b 444 M rr -- <<< ] 0
```